# angular 5 webpage is blank after refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I have following code and the webpage become blank after refresh, and based on the URL and nav bar, looks like no active route is selected.

```js
export class AuthService {
  ...
  constructor(private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router,
    private jwtHelper: JwtHelperService) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      const user = jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);
      userService.getUser(user).subscribe(
         data => { this.setCurrentUser(data), console.log(data) },
         error => console.log(error)
       );
    }
  }
```

And if I comment it out the subscription part, page works again. I feel it has something to do about the async nature of observable but I couldn’t figoure out exactly why. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your browser console? Does `userService.getUser(...)` return a `Promise` or an `Observable`? If it is a `Promise`, your code should be erroring because `Promise`s don't have a `subscribe (...)` method.

Comment: `getUser` returns an `observable` and there is no error. `data` is returned as expected.

Comment: Ok. You should update your question to use the term observable instead of promise. There really isn't enough details provided in your question to give guidance. Can you provide more details around how this service is used and more of the relevant code in the class?

Comment: Yeah just updated promise -> observable. This is the most relevant piece of code because I have pin pointed the problem which is the piece subscribing to the service. If I comment out those four lines, it works as expected. And I'm sure it's not the problem of the service since data comes back as expected.

Comment: Do you know any side effects of subscribing to observable in constructor? Because it's like partially constructed object before the observable completes, maybe never.

Comment: I have a feeling the issue lies with how you are using that data in your service and how that service is ultimately used. Are you holding onto the user data and providing that to other parts of your app in an asynchronous way? (e.g. through the use of a `Subject`)

Comment: No, `data` is used to set some flags in this component, that's it. I suspect routing is messed up by observable because if I refresh it twice, it kind of works but goes back to `/`. So if I'm at `/about`, refresh, url becomes `/`, page is blank, refresh again, url is still `/` but page is populated. Without those lines of subscribing, no matter how many times I refresh, page stays at `/about` and populated

Comment: Using observables in your constructor is perfectly fine and shouldn't cause issues strictly from their use. If you are getting redirected to `/` from refreshing when you are on `/about`, it sounds like an issue in your app routing. Are you using a route guard? Which app component is being shown to be added to the DOM when you refresh and it is empty? (e.g. what element is added to the DOM inside the `<router-outlet>`)

Comment: Good point that I'm using routing guard, and routing guard is based on the flags I set using `data`. And because `data` comes async, when pages renders, `canAdtive` is false and it redirects to `/`. It all make sense now. So what's a elegant way of solving this problem assuming I have to use the observable?

Comment: You'll probably want to expose the data asychronously by holding onto it in a subject (e.g  `BehaviorSubject`)

Comment: Please elaborate on that? I have no clue how subject can solve this problem. I feel I need a mechanism to delay valuation of routing guard.

Comment: The `CanActivate` method can return an asychronous response (i.e. `Observable<boolean>`) instead of a synchronous one (i.e. `boolean`). You can use the observable from that subject to transform it into such an observable. https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Comment: Thanks @DanielWStrimpel, I solved the problem by returning observable in `CanActivate`